# How do I increase value of variable after second loop?

Tags: java, variables, increment

I am making a for loop for my robot. Basically, I want to robot to move one more row that the one before it after each loop. I want to start at how many rows the user wants eventually keep going. So if the user wants 4 row to begin with, it'll start off moving 4 rows, then it'll move for 5 rows, then it'll move for 6 rows, etc.

I used variable makeLine and put it as makeLine++ so it would increase each time by one. However, when I do this, it starts off at 5 instead of 4 each time.

How do I make sure it starts off at the value the user inputted but also go up by 1 after that?

Here's a part of my code:

```
public void makeShape(Robot rob, int rows) {
    for(int count = 0; count < rows - 1; row++) {
        turnLeft(rob, rows);
        makeLine(rob, rows++);
        turnRight(rob);
        turnRight(rob);
        makeLine(rob, rows += 2);
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: You should show us the minimal amount of code that demonstrates this example.

Comment: perhaps try sth like `(makeLine-1)++` then.

Comment: I suspect we are about to get into block scope causing the variable to not update correctly, and closure providing the solution.

Comment: Unless it's not JavaScript -- good question.

Comment: public void makeShape(Robot rob, int rows) {
   for(int count = 0; count < rows - 1; row++) {
   turnLeft(rob, rows);
   makeLine(rob, rows++);
   turnRight(rob);
   turnRight(rob);
   makeLine(rob, rows += 2);

Answer (score 0):

If it moves 5 you want to move 4 rows. I think You using loop by initializing by var=5, it means loop will occur 6 times, because loop is start counting from zero to 5, it means 6, for better help post code. so I can realize bugs in code.